# Simple misunderstanding, getting started with neural-tangents

Tags: python, neural-network, jax

I copied and simplified this extremely simple code, just to get started playing with neural-tangents and jax

```
from jax import random
import neural_tangents as nt


init_fn, apply_fn, kernel_fn = nt.stax.serial(
    nt.stax.Dense(512), nt.stax.Relu(),
    nt.stax.Dense(1)
)

key1, _ = random.split(random.PRNGKey(1))
x = random.normal(key1, (1, 1))  # training features
y = random.uniform(key1, shape=(1, 1))  # training targets

predict_fn = nt.predict.gradient_descent_mse_ensemble(kernel_fn, x, y)
predictions = predict_fn(x, get='ntk')
print(y)
print("********")
print(predictions)
```

As I understand it, this trains an "infinitely wide" neural network to fit one single training example real number, to its desired target (also single real number).

So `y` and `predictions` should be the same. I'm training over one example, I have an infinitely powerful model, in my head these two should be the same. They aren't. It prints:

```
[[0.12462091]]
********
[[[[-0.45066586]]]]
```

What's more, if I changed the number of training examples to lets say 3, then the dimensions of the two prints now mismatch! I expected to find two vectors of three numbers each. What I got was:

```
[[0.6283829 ]
 [0.53268707]
 [0.89792836]]
********
[[[[0.0453045 ]
   [0.01134446]
   [0.17562252]]]


 [[[0.01215818]
   [0.00304447]
   [0.0471311 ]]]


 [[[0.1367114 ]
   [0.03423319]
   [0.5299607 ]]]]
```

It's clear I have a fatal misunderstanding. The docs didn't help me. Can anyone shed some light on the issue?